# NGINX - reverse proxy for Kibana using HTTPS

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, kibana

I installed the Elastic Stack (Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana) on Docker in Ubuntu Server.
All containers are in one docker network in bridge mode. I forced SSL in the Kibana configuration file, so it can only be opened using HTTPS. In the local DNS I added an entry kibana.home.com (home.com is only example) pointing to the server's IP address. By typing https://kibana.home.com:5601 in the web browser, the Kibana page opens and everything works well.

The problem has started when I wanted to secure the server.
I need port 5601 to be inaccessible from the outside and all network traffic to go through a reverse proxy.
I tryed to do it using Nginx but I have never used Nginx before. Probably I do something incorrectly. I added the Nginx installation to the docker-compose file and created the following Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/privateKey.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         https://kibana:5601;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - elk

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
        HOST_DNS: $HOST_DNS
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/templates/
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/templates/
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: certs
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: Examplepass1
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/pipelines.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/templates
        target: /usr/share/logstash/templates
      - type: volume
        source: certs
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/certs
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/mib
        target: /usr/share/logstash/mib
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5044:5044"
      - "9600:9600"
      - "5514:5514"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/index-pattern/
        target: /usr/share/kibana/index-pattern/
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: certs
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
  certs:
```

Unfortunately, when I try to connect (using both DNS and IP addresses) I get the 501 Bad Gateway message. Could you please explain me what did I do wrong? I would like to configure everything like this:

[Connection Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g9GC.png)

Comment: You don't need to enable SSL in kibana, nginx will do SSL termination instead. Show your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @IvanShatsky sure. I added docker-compose file content in main thread (too long for a comment).

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

To make the port 5601 inaccessible from the outside you should remove following parameter from kibana service:

```
ports:
   -"5601:5601"
```

To make your 3 services accessible by separated subdomains you should create separated 3 server blocks in nginx config for each subdomains like this:

```
server {
...
   server_name kibana.home.com;
...
}

server {
...
   server_name elastic.home.com;
...
}

server {
...
   server_name logstash.home.com;
...
}
```

You can turn on nginx debugging as mentioned [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The domain is only added on the local DNS side as an A record pointing to the server's IP address. I haven't removed port 5601 yet, because if I did, I would lose access to Kibana until I set up Nginx properly. Adding `server_name kibana.home.com;` to the configuration file did not help.

Comment: What is result of execution the command docker logs [NGINX_CONTAINER_NAME] ?